# How can I tell if a matrix is diagonalizable knowing only the trace, one eigenvalue, and a result of the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Given $A$, a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and:

$\mathrm{tr}(A) = −2$,

$\mathrm{rk}(A−2I)< 3$,

$\chi_A(1) = −8$

($\mathrm{tr}$: trace, $\mathrm{rk}$: rank, and $\chi_A(x)$: characteristic polynomial)

How can I tell if the matrix is diagonalizable? What are the eigenvalues?
I know that given $\mathrm{rk}(A−2I)< 3$, $2$ must an eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$, at least. But I don't know what information does "$\chi_A(1)=−8$" provide me.

Comment: You know that $\chi(x)=(x-2)(x-a)(x-b)$

Comment: $\chi_A(1) = −8$ means that $A-I$ has three nonzero eigenvalues, two of which are negative; what does this say about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: No, χA(1)=−8 means that A has 3 eigenvalues. χA gives information about A: If it were written χ(A-I)(1)=−8 it would give information about A-I. I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two missing eigenvalues, other than the known eigenvalue $2$. The first equation tells you that their sum is $-4$. The last equation gives you another equation: since $\chi_A(t) = (t-2)(t-\lambda)(t-\mu)$, plugging in $t=1$ allows you to solve for $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time an effort to reply. I was very stuck and couldn't see clearly. Your reply was very useful!

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic polynomial is $(X-2)(X^2+bX+c)$.  The trace is the coefficient of $X^2$ that is:$b-2=-2$.

The last equation enables you to find $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I don't understand how I know that the trace is the coefficient (say "a") of X^2.

Comment: @MaiLen multiply out the general characteristic polynomial $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$ and see what the coefficient of $x^2$ is. This generalizes to any order of polynomial, of course.

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

- $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=-2$

then we can exclude

- $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=2$

suppose

- $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=2\implies \lambda_3=-6$

then

- $\chi_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+6)\implies \chi_A(1)=7 $

therefore  $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3$.

Comment: How do you know the two eigenvalues other than $2$ cannot be equal?

Comment: @TedShifrin We know that at least one eigenvalue must be equal to $2$. They cannot be all equal to 2. And also we can exclude that two are equal to $2$ because in this case the third should be equal to $-6$. Therefore we have three distinct eigenvalues. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. Did you address my question?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry I don't understand you observation, probably you are right but I don't get your point. Could you please explain which step is not correct? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi - you've explained why there can't be two eigenvalues that are $2$, but you have not explained why two of the eigenvalues cannot be $-2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have the same question. You very well proved that 2 has a multiplicity of 1, but the remaining eigenvalues could be equal. I think that your proof needs an extra step where it shows that if λ1=2, λ2≠λ3.

Comment: @MaiLen Ah yes of course, I’ll revise that. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes you’re right, thanks!